# Accessing properties from another form

Tags: c#, forms, properties

I have a form with some elements in it. I want to access the data from that form in my main one. I tried doing the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.emailServer = textBox1.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.emailServerPort = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.emailServerSsl = (radioButton1.Checked == true) ? true : false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            this.Close();
        }
```

I can load it perfectly fine in the existing form using this code:

```
private void EmailSettings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.emailServer;
            numericUpDown1.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.emailServerPort;
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.emailServerSsl == true)
            {
                radioButton1.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                radioButton1.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```

HOWEVER, my issue is that I can't access `Properties` from my main form. So I still can't access the data from that form. How can I access the data either from properties in my main form or from another form?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897399/access-variables-between-cs-files-in-wpf-c-sharp/35897626#35897626 ... this is exactly your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed settings  .You can access to settings from every where from your project .
Here you have set settings in form2 then you can access it from main form

```
 var setting=Properties.Settings.Default.YourSetting;
```

If namespace in form2 and main form are different
You must write like

```
var setting=namespaceOfForm2.Properties.Settings.Default.YourSetting;
```

Also you can below solution

On the second form create a property

```
public yourType yourProperty { get;set;}
```

Store your data to it

```
yourProperty=yourData;
// set this.DialogResult property if you successfully     stored data
this.DialogResult=DialogResult.OK;
```

And from main form  get it

```
Form2 f=new Form2();
if(f.ShowDialog==DialogResult.OK)
{
    var yourData=f.yourProperty;
}
```

Example:

On form2:

```
public string Name { get; set;}
public void methodThatYouSetData()
{
    Name=txtbx.Text;
    this.DialogResult=DialogResult.OK;  
}
```

On main form:

```
Form2 f=new Form2();
if(f.ShowDialog==DialogResult.OK)
{
    string Name=f.Name;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your method (code) a bit more? I can't understand how to implement it. Also, how would I load back the values for the other form afterwards?